# How to configure IBM MQ username and password in jboss stanalone.xml for JBoss andMQ connec

Tags: java, security, jboss, ibm-mq

I try to connect with IBM MQ from Jboss.
So i configured RA in standalone.xml.
I given all the configuration properties as below.
But am getting the below exception.

```
please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').\",
```

The Configuration as given below

```
 <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/MQConnectionFactory" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MQConnectionFactory">
                            <config-property name="hostName">
                                localhost
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="password">
                               sdadsadsadasd
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager">
                                TEST
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="port">
                                1415
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="channel">
                                TEST.CHANNEL
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="transportType">
                                CLIENT
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="username">
                                testusermq
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
```

Thee user group also mapped to MQ from windows side. Am using Jboss 7 and IBM MQ 9

Comment: When you receive the 2035 on the jboss side what does the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG have in it?

Comment: @JoshMc am not able to see the errror log in Manager side in version 9.0

Comment: Do you mean there is no error or you don't have access?   If the later can yiu ask someone with access.   There are many causes of 2035 and the queue manager log will give specifics.

Comment: @JoshMc yes another thing i noticed in the jboss log `Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager '' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.` the port i given is 1415 but its hitting 1414 only, not sure why the default port is hitting instead of what i configured.

Comment: The 2035 and the "Caused by" just indicate the queue manager sent back a 2035 response. The causes of a 2035 are many and you need to look at the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG for info on the exact cause.  You answered my question with "Yes" but still doesn't help.  Did you check the AMQERR01.LOG and found no error? Do you not have access to view the AMQERR01.LOG?  Please be specific in your response.  If you have not checked either directly or via someone else that has access please do, this will be required to know what the cause is with out speculating and provided a number of causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to configure in the listener side. ie MDB side also we need to configure all the username, channel, etc. Then i can able to connect. Not enough to give in the resource level

```
<message-driven>
<ejb-name>TESTMDB</ejb-name>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>java:/queue/TESTQUEUE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>hostName</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.HOST}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>port</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.PORT}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>channel</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.CHANNEL}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>queueManager</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.QMGR}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>transportType</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.TRANSPORT.TYPE}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>useJNDI</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${USE.JNDI}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>maxPoolDepth</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${OFS.MAX.POOL.DEPTH}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>username</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.USERNAME}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>password</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${MQ.PASSWORD}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jms/TestJQueueConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
                <jndi-name>java:/MQConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
            </resource-ref>
            <message-destination-ref>
                <message-destination-ref-name>jms/ReplyQueue</message-destination-ref-name>
                <jndi-name>java:/queue/testReplyQueue</jndi-name>
            </message-destination-ref>
        </message-driven>
```